# Empty override C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, overriding, listener

Having the Observer pattern.

```
class Observer
{
   virtual eventA()=0;
   virtual eventB()=0;
    ...
   virtual eventZ()=0;
}
```

The Observer class cannot be changed, but my class is only interested in the event B. Therefore I need to:

```
class MyObserver{
    eventA() override {}
    eventB() override { /* Do something */ }
    eventC() override {}
    ...
    eventZ() override {}
}
```

It is overhead to empty-implement all events, specially if you have a policy to always implement in cpp files (except templates obviously).

Does C++11 offer any keyword for that? Like

```
...
eventC() override = empty;
...
```

In that way, I wouldn't need to add the empty implementation in the CPP file.

Comment: `{}` is shorter than `= empty` :)

Comment: Going to the CCP file and write
void MyObserver::eventA()
{
}
Is longer :). Remember what I mentioend about the policy. We should implement always in cpp file. Inlines outside the class. Even making the functions inline would require to implemet them ouside the class in the header file, which is more code to write :(

Comment: It is also super annoying to comment out all events parameters because the unused variables are treated as errors...

Comment: If having a default implementation of nothing is common (or intended), you're probably better off not making the base class use pure virtual functions - they imply that an implementation _must_ be provided. Of course, sometimes there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for doesn't exist.

Anyway, you can do this:

```
struct Observer {
    virtual ~Observer() = 0;
    virtual void eventA() {}
    virtual void eventB() {}
    // ...
    virtual void eventZ() {}
};

Observer::~Observer() { }

struct MyObserver: Observer {
    void eventB() override { /* Do something */ }
};
```

Here you have:

- `Observer` still abstract (thanks to its destructor), so you cannot instantiate objects of this type
- A default empty implementation for all of your methods
- No need to define empty bodies in your derived classes for those methods in which you are not interested

Thus, as a consequence:

```
int main() {
    // This compiles and works as expected
    Observer *O = new MyObserver;
    // The following line doesn't compile
    // Observer *O = new Observer;
}
```

Ok, but you said that:

> The Observer class cannot be changed

In this case, you can define an intermediate class that is not instantiable from which to derive, as an example:

```
struct IntermediateObserver: Observer {
    virtual ~IntermediateObserver() = 0;
    void eventA() override {}
    void eventB() override {}
    // ...
    void eventZ() override {}
};

IntermediateObserver::~IntermediateObserver() { }

struct MyObserver: IntermediateObserver {
    void eventB() override { /* Do something */ }
};
```

From now on, derive all your custom observers from `IntermediateObserver` and that's all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I cannot modify the Observer clas

Answer (score 1):

Your design violates the [Interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), stating that  no client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use/need.
Maybe you should reconsider the design and create several Observer base classes, one for each event?

If you can not change the design, use `{}`, there is no `empty`, `default` or `delete` for user-written functions.

> Does C++11 offer any keyword for that?

No